# Gulp Not Properly Compiling SASS/SCSS

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I installed Gulp and gulp-sass in the package.json file, and then compiled some basic SCSS. However, when I tried to cut/paste over some more complex SCSS file and then compile it with 'gulp sass' it gave me this error:

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: sass/style.scss
Error: Undefined variable: "$fs-base".
        on line 1 of sass/style.scss
>> @mixin font-base($font-size: $fs-base, $font-weight: 300, $color: $black) {
   -----------------------------^
```

Why won't Gulp compile this SCSS?

```
@mixin font-base($font-size: $fs-base, $font-weight: 300, $color: $black) {
    font: {
      family: $ff-base;
      size: $font-size;
      weight: $font-weight;
    }
    color: $color;
  } 

  @mixin font-alt($font-size: $fs-base, $color: $black) {
    font: {
      family: $ff-alt;
      size: $font-size;
    }
    color: $color;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 10.3em;
  }

  // ===== Styles ===== //

  body {
    @include font-base;
    line-height: 1.6;

    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 5fr 2fr 1fr;

    grid-template-rows: 10em 50vh auto 10em;

  }
```

And this is the repo: https://github.com/jwolfe890/CSSGrid

Comment: Declare $fs-base

Comment: sass will error if you dont declare the variables value before trying to use them.

Comment: thanks, it's working now. i thought it was a Gulp issue since i was new to it.